# About the geodesic coordinates, and their conversion into cartesian ones

Tags: analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems, polar-coordinates, spherical-coordinates, geodesy

This is more a sort of "let me know if I'm right" question, rather than a real question, but I thought that if is there a place where I can find true and solid trustful answers then it's here.

Suppose someone gives me those coordinates:

$$109^{\circ} 39'\ N$$

$$30^{\circ} 10'\ W$$

If I want to localize this place over the Earth surface, via cartesian coordinates (or better: if I simply want to convert them into cartesian), here is what I understood to be the process.

Please, notice that this is **what I understood** so if it's wrong you have to correct me because I did not find any book or notes where this has been explained clearly.

**First step**

Transform the coordinates I got into "true angles" that is: latitude $\theta$ and longitude $\phi$ according to the DMS transformation:

$$\theta = 109 + \frac{39}{60} = 109.65$$

$$\phi = 30 + \frac{10}{60} = 39.16$$

**Second Step**

Using the polar coordinates to find the space vector, that is:

$$x = R\sin\theta\cos\phi$$

$$y = R\sin\theta\sin\phi$$

$$z = R\cos\theta$$

Where $R = $ Earth radius.

Finally I will obtain the space vector $\mathbf{r} = (x, y, z)$ for the place in question.

**Final Question**

Is this all right? Are there any errors or information I shall take into account? Any remark?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

You have a BIG mistake, which is the limit of the lattitude are $90S$ which is the South Pole to $90N$ which is the North Pole. You are here mentioning a lattitude which is 109N. This is outside the range. I assume your angles should be $109W$ and $30N$ which is somewhere Texas....

Fix your coordinates then, we can verify your transformation .

Comment: Oh, so you mean I shall have something like $109$ for $\phi$ and $39$ for $\theta$?

Answer (score 0):

if your $z-$axis travels from south to north pole, then $z = R \sin(lattitude\, angle)$ where North is assumed positive and south is assumed negative. (Center of earth is System of coordinates center). Consequently $x = R \cos(lattitude\, angle) \cos(longitude\, angle)$ and $y = R \cos(lattitude\, angle) \sin(longitude\, angle)$ for longitude angle : East is positive and West is negative limit is [-180,180[